# Why are some beers warm and some cold?

Tags: serving, ale

While out at my local I always like to try new beers, and as I was going through a few different beers and I noticed that almost all of them all had varying temperatures. Some where ice cold whilst some were warmer I understand that this is on purpose but I'm not sure why?

So why is it that some beers are served Cold and why are some served Warm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Why is it that some beers are served Cold and why are some served Warm?**

At what temperature should a beer be served can be answered by the following statement:

> Most beers have an ideal serving temperature. There’s a chart below outlining which styles are served at what temperature, but as a general rule the temperature at which to serve a beer is correlated to the strength of the beer. **As beers go up in alcohol, they are generally drunk at a warmer temperature.** This is because stronger beers often are sipped slowly, and enjoyed for their complexity of flavor and aroma while weaker beers are often consumed for refreshment. For no style is this more apparent than American macro lagers, which are generally drunk so cold that you can’t taste them. There’s a reason those big brewers want people to drink their beers at tongue-numbing temperatures. As they warm up, they don’t taste very good. - [The Craft Beer Temple.](http://craftbeertemple.com/videoblog/serving-beer/)
>
> **Very Cold: 35-40 degrees**
>
> •American Adjunct Lagers (“Macros”)
>
> •Malt Liquors
>
> •Light or low alcohol beers
>
> **Cold: 40-45 degrees**
>
> •Pilsner
>
> •Light-bodied lagers
>
> •Kolsch
>
> •Belgian Wit
>
> •Hefeweizen
>
> •Berliner weisse
>
> •American Wheat
>
> **Cool: 45-50 degrees**
>
> •American Pale Ales
>
> •Medium-bodied lagers
>
> •India Pale Ale (IPA)
>
> •Porters
>
> •Alt
>
> •Irish Stouts
>
> •Sweet Stout
>
> **Cellar Temp: 50-55 degrees**
>
> •Sour Ales
>
> •Lambic/Gueuze
>
> •English Bitter
>
> •Strong Ales
>
> •Baltic Porters
>
> Blockquote•Bocks
>
> •Scotch Ales
>
> •Belgian Ales
>
> •Trappist Ales
>
> **Warm: 55-60 degrees**
>
> •Imperial Stouts
>
> •Belgian Quads
>
> •Belgian Strong Ales
>
> •Barley Wines
>
> •Old Ales
>
> •Dopplebock
>
> •Eisbock

Comment: Thank you this really explains it nicely an i now have a handy list to go against so i know if my beer should be cold or warm

Comment: @JamieEltringham Glad to be of some help!

Comment: I always come across those in the warmer ranges being served too cold. Amazing what happens when you actually drink them at the right temperature, their flavour opens up quite a bit.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think anyone would deliberately or professionally serve *warm* beer, if by warm you mean something close to body temperature. Generally speaking, cask ale (as opposed to pressurised keg beer) is served, in the UK at least, and according to CAMRA's website, at cellar temperature: 12-14 C (54-57 F), whereas lager and keg beer is usually served much colder.

So much for the purist. My preference is always for cask ale to be served cool, but not cold, so that the flavours can be properly appreciated. Good quality lager should be served colder, and I prefer Czech pilsners at around 6-8 C - about the same temperature as you'd want white wine to be. But on a burning hot day in the African sunshine (where I'm from), there is nothing as refreshing as an ice-cold (and I mean **ice**-cold) ordinary mass-market lager, straight out of the bottle. You can't distinguish tastes as readily at those temperatures. Refreshment is the key there: you don't really care about taste in those circumstances (if you did you'd be drinking something else).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you know what sake is sake is traditional wine that served hot I have experience cold and hot it a lot taster when it hot try some go to a Japanese store ask them u want to try hot sake

Comment: I was focusing on beer in this question but thanks for the information